# How to parse "Content" output when POSTing from Powershell?

Tags: json, powershell, parsing, curl, post

I have this code, that loops through some JSON files on my local drive and POSTs them to a URL with cURL:

```
$negativeTests = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\ME\Documents\folder\folder\"
#Write-Host $negativeTests;
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $negativeTests.Count; $i++) {
    $tempFile = Get-Content $negativeTests[$i].PSPath
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://myWebsite.com/ext/ext/ext -Method POST -Body $tempFile
}
```

This code, when run, gives this output from the server in the format:

> StatusCode        : 304
>
> StatusDescription : OK
>
> Content           : {"success": NO, "errors": [ERROR], "stuffs": 100}
>
> RawContent        : HTsP/5.1 42 OK
>
> X-f-Options: oasdf
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Length: 234
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Content-Type: application/???; charset=ut480a
>
> Date: Tue, 29 Jun 2060 11:72:83 GMT
>
> S...
>
> Forms             : {}
>
> Headers           : {[X-Frame-Options, SAMEORIGIN], [Connection, keep-alive], [Content-Length, 52], [Cache-Control, no-cache]...}
>
> Images            : {} ?
>
> InputFields       : {} a
>
> Links             : {"no"}
>
> ParsedHtml        : mshstml.?
>
> RawContentLength  : 234

How can I get and parse through the `Content: {"success":NO,"errors":[ERROR],"stuffs":100}` section of this output? I would ideally then check to see if the file uploaded successfully or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of the `Content` property looks like a JSON string, so you should be able to convert it to a PowerShell object like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest ... | select -Expand Content | ConvertFrom-Json
```

and then process the `success`, `errors` and `stuffs` property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

If your content is JSON and you have Powershell 4.0, `Invoke-RestMethod` could be easier to use that `Invoke-WebRequest`. It will automatically unpack the JSON response from the content and parse it. It also has a parameter to read the body directly from an input file, `InFile`:

```
$negativeTests = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\ME\Documents\folder\folder\"
#Write-Host $negativeTests;
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $negativeTests.Count; $i++) {
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://myWebsite.com/ext/ext/ext -Method POST -InFile $negativeTests[$i].FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like see full content just add `| Select -ExpandProperty Content` in the end of the CURL command in Powershell, like this:

```
curl -v -Method Post -Uri 'https://myapi.com/myMethod' -headers @{"Content-Type"= "application/json"} -Body '{"myToken": "123"}' | Select -ExpandProperty Content
```